# JSON structure for serializing into Dictionary

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, controller

In an MVC controller i have below piece of code

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult One(Dictionary<Guid, int[]> groups)
 {
   return Json(groups);
 }
```

What is the json structure i need to provide for it to be properly serialized into the Dictionary ?
Tried below:

```
{
  "Key": "4e89af43-59c8-492b-b646-1185e3f8776c",
  "Value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

and

```
{
    "groups": {
        "Key": "4e89af43-59c8-492b-b646-1185e3f8776c",
        "Value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems `GUID` are not meant to be serialized when inside the dictionary. Here is the error i received

[image]

So i had to change my Dictionary to below and the parameters to be sent like the next piece of code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult One(Dictionary<string, int[]> groups)
 {
   return Json(groups);
 }
```

JSON Input

```
{"groups":[
    {
        "Key": "4e89af43-59c8-492b-b646-1185e3f8776c",
        "Value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
]}
```

Thanks to anyone and everyone who helped

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be serialized into "Dictionary", you need the following structure:

```
{
    "Key": "Value",
    "Key": "Value",
    "Key": "Value"
}
```

In your case it will be the following object:

```
{
    "4e89af43-59c8-492b-b646-1185e3f8776c": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "4e89af43-1234-492b-b646-1185e3f8776c": [0, -1, -2],
    "4e89af43-59c8-5678-b646-1185e3f8776c": [7]
}
```

In terms of JSON request in ASP.NET you probably will need to wrap it in a object corresponding to a variable name:

```
{
    groups: {
        "4e89af43-59c8-492b-b646-1185e3f8776c": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "4e89af43-1234-492b-b646-1185e3f8776c": [0, -1, -2],
        "4e89af43-59c8-5678-b646-1185e3f8776c": [7]
    }
}
```

At least, it definitely should be so in case of `Dictionary<string, int[]>`.
You have a `Guid` as a key and I hope that `ASP.NET` will properly serialize Guid as a string.